# Does the URL needs to be HTTPS for a messenger webview?

Tags: webview, botframework, messenger

I tried putting a HTTP URL in a Messenger Webview and the bot is crashing.

Comment: Could you please share more details. What are you doing exactly and what happens. Do you have some code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, per Facebook Messenger's documentation, Webviews have to be HTTPS and they have to be whitelist in the Page Settings. For more details, take a look at Facebook Messenger's documentation on [Whitelisting URLs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting).